# In python, if y==0 then, do something, if y!=0 then do the other things

Tags: python

everyone. I am a university student. and I am calculating the scores of dart board for at least more than 30 hours.

So, basically, I have to do divide the dart board into 20 different angles and give it "value"-that is 1 to 20. and subdivide it into different radius.
And, I have to do something if y == 0 and do other things if y!=0.

Oh, you do not necessarily read all these code. that will be waste of your time.haha. So,

The problem is if I put x,y like -30.00
22.00 than python understand 22.00 as 0.00 (so,22.00==0.00)
also, in this case x =90.71 and y = -43.01

I do not know what problem is,please save me.
Thanks a lot for reading this question and I wish you have a wonderful day.haha

Oh, this is my first question, I do not know how to properly code it here.so if you do not mind, I would replace it into screen capture.

```html
x = float(input())
y = float(input())
if y == 0.00:
    if 0 <= x < 6.3:
        score = 50
    elif 6.3 <= x < 15.9:
        score =25
    elif 15.9 <= x < 97.4:
        score = 6
    elif 97.4 <= x< 107:
        score =18
    elif 107 <= x < 160.4:
        score = 6
    elif 160.4 <= x < 170:
        score = 12
    elif -6.3 <= x < 0:
        score = 50
    elif -15.9 <= x < -6.3:
        score = 25
    elif -97.4 <= x < -15.9:
        score = 16
    elif -107 <= x< -97.4:
        score = 48
    elif -160.4 <= x < -107:
        score = 16
    elif -170 <= x < -160.4:
        score = 32
    else:
        score = 0
print(score)
    
if y != 0:
    import math

    angle = math.atan2(y, x)
    if angle < 0:
        angle= angle + (2)*(math.pi)

    r = ((x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 0.5)

    if r <= 6.3:
        print(50)
    elif 6.3 < r <= 15.9:
        print(25)
    
    if r > 15.9:
        if angle >= (39 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 6
        elif angle <= (1 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 6
        elif (1 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (3 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 5
        elif (3 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (5 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 4
        elif (5 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (7 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 3
        elif (7 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (9 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 2
        elif (9 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (11 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 1
        elif (11 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (13 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 20
        elif (13 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (15 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 19
        elif (15 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (17 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 18
        elif (17 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (19 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 17
        elif (19 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (21 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 16
        elif (21 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (23 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 15
        elif (23 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (25 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 14
        elif (25 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (27 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 13
        elif (27 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (29 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 12
        elif (29 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (31 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 11
        elif (31 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (33 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 10
        elif (33 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (35 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 9
        elif (35 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (37 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 8
        elif (37 / 20) * math.pi < angle <= (39 / 20) * math.pi:
            value = 7
        if 15.9 <= r < 97.4:
            a = 1
        elif 97.4 <= r < 107:
            a = 3
        elif 107 <= r <160.4:
            a = 1
        elif 160.4 <= r < 170:
            a = 2
        else:
            a =0
        print(value * a)
```

Comment: How do you input the numbers? Do you put it like "-30.00 22.00" with space in between or one at a time?

Comment: how does `-30.00` become `x =90.71` and `y = -43.01` is there some geometry/trig involved?

Comment: also, for "python understand 22.00 as 0.00 (so,22.00==0.00)", maybe use `value = angle % 20`

Comment: If you are repeating if statements like this, try to think of a better way to write your code that is more concise and has less repetition. For example, in the case of `y == 0`, you could make an array of (start, end, score) tuples, and have a loop go through the array and use the given score if `x` is between start and end. In the case of `y != 0` and `r > 15.9`, you could probably have an array of ints, and index it by `math.ceil(0.5 + angle / (math.pi / 10))`.

Comment: Thank u, I applied your answer and it worked well. When I posted this question previously, I didn't know about "for loop" but the assignment was about applying "for loop"

Answer (score 0):

If "python understand 22.00 as 0.00" means "python try to print score", it would because of indent.
After you calculate score when y==0.0, line "print(score)" should be indented.

```py
    ...
    elif -160.4 <= x < -107:
        score = 16
    elif -170 <= x < -160.4:
        score = 32
    else:
        score = 0
    print(score)

if y != 0:
    import math
    ...
```

Comment: Really! Thanks a lot. Um....To be very honest, it was not because of the indentation rather it was due to my mistake of setting domain, which is x and also because of the fact that atan2 only displays result from -pi to pi.